# Java 8 Spark: Missing content for multipart request

Tags: java, multipartform-data, httpserver

**RESOLVED - please see the EDIT comment below**

I'm following [the guide](http://deniz.dizman.org/file-uploads-using-spark-java-micro-framework/) of Java spark on how to upload a file using post request.

My upload request header and body:

```
    Content Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=zQqNxBjHLrzzCCIjVOhwqHUxRSkiHEz

    body: --zQqNxBjHLrzzCCIjVOhwqHUxRSkiHEz
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="test_file"
    Content-Type: application/octet-stream
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

    some text

    --zQqNxBjHLrzzCCIjVOhwqHUxRSkiHEz--
```

Using Java Spark framework' I have the following code:

```
Spark.before((request, response) -> {

            MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement = new MultipartConfigElement("/tmp");
            request.raw().setAttribute("org.eclipse.multipartConfig", multipartConfigElement);

            System.out.println(request.raw().getPart("file"));

});
```

However, when I try to run the example. I get the following exception:

```
 [qtp244774599-29] ERROR spark.webserver.MatcherFilter - 
    java.io.IOException: Missing content for multipart request
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.MultiPartInputStreamParser.parse(MultiPartInputStreamParser.java:480)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.MultiPartInputStreamParser.getParts(MultiPartInputStreamParser.java:402)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getPart(Request.java:2046)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getPart(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:361)
        at 
Main.lambda$main$0(Main.java:39)
        at 
Main$$Lambda$1/1190654826.handle(Unknown Source)
        at spark.SparkBase$2.handle(SparkBase.java:343)
        at spark.webserver.MatcherFilter.doFilter(MatcherFilter.java:120)
        at spark.webserver.JettyHandler.doHandle(JettyHandler.java:60)
```

**EDIT**

Found solution. Spark has recently released v2.3, which with HaiderAgha answer actually works. So the solution is to update to v2.3 and use `org.eclipse.jetty.multipartConfig` instead of `org.eclipse.multipartConfig`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This fix works only for spark 2.3!**

Instead of

```
request.raw().setAttribute("org.eclipse.multipartConfig",multipartConfigElement);
```

Use

```
request.raw().setAttribute("org.eclipse.jetty.multipartConfig",multipartConfigElement);
```

Comment: This fix actually works only for Spark 2.3, which was recently released. Anyway, I have marked this answer as the the solution, and added comment in my original post. Thanks!

Comment: This works for me.  What I did notice is that when using multipart/form-data you have to use the "parts" for *everything*, since spark can't handle it.  Garbage framework.